# Java android open google maps with Address

Tags: java, android

I want to open google maps when I have address: when I have a state, city , street, number of building. I can only open a google maps when I have a lat and lon. How I can do this?

Comment: nobody knows when you have all that. All depends on your code.

Comment: @VladMatvienko but can I geogoding a whole address to lat lon ? or can I open google maps with with adress ; Polska , Kraków, Teligi 13  ?

Comment: you can do both. to get the lat-long of the address: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+get+latitude+and+longitude+from+address&oq=android+get+latitude+and+longitude+&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.8479j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 . To open maps with the address: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+get+latitude+and+longitude+from+address&oq=android+get+latitude+and+longitude+&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.8479j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android+open+google+maps+with+the+address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get coordinates from adress by use Geocoder and after open google maps by coordinates

Something like that

```
   mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    Log.v("ddd", mAddress);

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            //To initialice list of address
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
                    //To put the address in list
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(mAddress, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            //Get Latitude and longitude
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    mLongitude = address.getLongitude();
    mlatitude = address.getLatitude();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Here it's really simple to launch google maps from your application:
//geo:0,0 if you don't have lat/lng for the location and just wanna search using address.

Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=pass the address here");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
//set package to "com.google.android.apps.maps" so that only google maps is opened.
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```